# Divide a single column of comma separated values into separate columns of frequency-Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in my excel sheet in which the participant has to choose the top three items he/she likes among A,B,C,D,E and F.
So, the entries of that column(comma separated) are like:

- A,C,D
- C,E,F
- A,B,C

.
.
.
Now, is there any way to divide this column into 6 separate columns of frequencies as

- A B C D E F
- 1 0 1 1 0 0
- 0 0 1 0 1 1
- 1 1 1 0 0 0

Comment: I have a column which contains comma separated values. I have no idea of how to separate them into 6 individual columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.g. this formula:

`=IFERROR(SIGN(SEARCH(B$1,$A2)),0)`

- `SEARCH(B$1,$A2)` checks whether letter in the header exists in first column string (returns position if yes, error if no)
- If letter found, `SIGN(...)` converts result (position) to `1`
- If not found `=IFERROR(...,0)` converts error to `0`

[image]